# homeAsUpIndicator styles don't apply on default Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-styles

There are lots of questions about homeAsUpIndicator and I've tried all with no results.

The code is simple. I have only the code of the default NavigationDrawer from Android Studio 1.0.1, with appcompat and building for SDK21.

I want to change de homeAsUpIndicator, but only the programmatically way is working:

```
actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.custom_indicator);
```

When I try to move that to the styles.xml, it doesn't work:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/custom_indicator</item>
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/custom_indicator</item>
</style>
```

The colors are applied correctly, but not the homeAsUpIndicator. What I can try? It's the default project and I'v tried the two simple solutions that seem to appear everywhere. The Java sentence is only a workaround, as I consider is best placed on styles.xml. What can be happening? Is the default project overriding my style?

Comment: Are you setting the activities to use `AppTheme` in your manifest?